# TabBarController switch views in TabBarItem

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, tableview

I have a app based off the default xcode "Tab Bar Application" template. It has 3 tabBar Items that each load their own xib FirstView.xib, SecondView.xib, and ThirdView.xib. What i would like is a UIButton on the FirstView.xib that loads the FirstAltView.xib where the FirstView.xib is. Can someone please post some sample code on how to do this or a complete xCode project because i cannot figure out how to link the view controllers together.

Here is a flow chart of how the flow of my app should be. Basicly there is a button on the login window that will load the table view.
[alt text http://i51.photobucket.com/albums/f373/ROBKID/flowchart.png](http://i51.photobucket.com/albums/f373/ROBKID/flowchart.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is trying to figure out how to build a simular structure to this app i highly recommend http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/node/47 its standford Universities iphone development class and that lesson was very helpful in explaining this concept to me.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is well-documented with sample code all over the interwebs. Just remember that you cannot push a tab bar controller onto a navigation controller stack. You can, however, use a navigation controller as a tab bar view controller.

I would start with the [Apple documentation on programming view controllers](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CombiningViewControllers/CombiningViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH104-SW1).

Best regards,

Comment: Could you please provide me with a link to a actual project I have searched fairly extensively for this and i have not found a case where someone is switching views under a tabbaritem