# In my project about tabbarcontroller and dismissviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

The `tabbarcontroller` from index is 1 present a controller, when controller dismiss, how can make `tabbarcontroller` index become a 2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TabBarController switch views in TabBarItem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134038/tabbarcontroller-switch-views-in-tabbaritem)

Answer (score 1):

when you dismiss the controller, you can use

```
self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex: XX
```

to switch the viewController of tabbarControler

Comment: thanks for your answer, although it's not that i want, maybe the description is not clear enough, this question is about login page, when it did not login,seleted tabbar index of 1,it will present controller of login page, login page has a back button, when click back button, will back tabbar index of 1,but this controller viewdidload ,i do a judge, if not login, it will present login  page , I don't  know where i should write "self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex: XX"!

Answer (score 0):

**use this one line of code when you dismiss your controller**

```
yourTabBar.selectedIndex=1;//int value eg. 1,2,3,4
```